# Destroy layout after using setContentView

Tags: java, android

On one button I called a layout like so:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_form);
```

On the other I wanna destroy that layout. How can I do it ?

Comment: Set another layout with no views added or you can call rootView.removeAllViews();

Comment: Can you give  me an example of how to define rootView?

Comment: rootView is your top most layout

Answer (score 0):

U can use `rootView.removeAllViews();` to remove all views from layout, for example

Your layout is

```
             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llRootView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                             .......

             </LinearLayout>
```

Then you can call `llRootView.removeAllViews();` to remove all views from this linear layout

**EDIT**

To Temporary remove views from layout you can change its visibility using

```
llRootView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

To make it visible again use

```
llRootView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: To declare it I would do, LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llRootView). Is that correct ?

Comment: Hi, so, it clears the screen, removes all views **but** the layout. I tried doing [this code](http://prntscr.com/e87roi) involving the parent layout but it crashes.